# Where should I store disabled plugins?

Tags: plugins, directory

I have several plugins that I occasionally use for maintenance/import tasks etc. but I don't need them available in the plugins admin most of the time.

As my site has quite a large number of plugins, I was wondering if there is any advantage to moving them completely out of the 'wp-content/plugins' directory? I thought I might create a directory 'wp-content/plugins-disabled' and put them in there. Is it bad practice to create my own directories like this in 'wp-content'?

Comment: I would consider it bad practice to put them in a folder like `wp-content/plugins-disabled`, as the structure suggests that WordPress actually uses something like that. In WordPress, disabling plugins is handled by the plugin interface and plugin API, not by plugin folder location. And, as said in the answers: if you don't use a plugin, just delete it :-).

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. So there's no performance hit in storing disabled plugins in WordPress? The Codex says to Disable *and* Delete, so I was concerned that a large number of disabled-only plugins might cause performance issues: [WordPress Optimization/WordPress Performance](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/WordPress_Performance)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need an extra directory for storing your disabled plugins. Better keep them there default location (/plugins/) and whenever you need to reactive just simple one click away! Or, if you think that plugin doesn't help you in future, just DELETE it!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well today.

If you don't need the plugins then you can just deactivate them but if you don't want these plugins available in the plugins admin menu also then you can store the plugins in the  'wp-content/plugins-disabled' directory as you are thinking because i don't see any disadvantages of storing it there and reactivating it will be much easier.

Updating the WordPress will not affect the plugins stored in the 'wp-content/plugins-disabled' directory but if you are not using any plugin at all then it's better to delete it.

Cheers,
Vinod Dalvi